# Webシステムにおける3層構造のWebサーバと、アプリケーションサーバ内の3層構造（MVC）のコントローラの違いについて

Tags: http, model-view-controller, サーバー管理

「WebシステムにおけるWebサーバ」と、「MVCアーキテクチャにおけるコントローラ」の違いについて質問です。

Webアプリケーションでは2パターンの3層構造が存在すると思います。
1. Webシステムにおける3層構造（Webサーバ・アプリケーションサーバ・DBサーバ）
2. アプリケーション層における3層構造（MVC（モデル・ビュー・コントローラ））

このうち、**Webサーバ**と**コントローラ**の役割を以下のように認識しております。
1の**Webサーバ**も、2の**コントローラ**も、
「クライアントから指定されたURLに従って、下位層（アプリケーションサーバ、モデル）へ処理をリクエストする」

また、Webシステムの3層構造と、アプリケーション層における3層構造（MVC）が併存するシステムは、添付画像のようなシステムになるかと思います。
ここで、2つ質問です。
①このとき、**Webサーバ**と**コントローラ**はどんな違いがあるのでしょうか？
②**Webサーバ**が、指定されたURLに従ってアプリケーションサーバにリクエストを送った後、
**コントローラ**が、さらにURLに従ってモデルへ処理を依頼するという、2重でURLに従った処理を行っている理由は何でしょうか？

上記の認識等に間違いがございましたら、ご指摘願います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかも。[MVC、3 層アーキテクチャから設計を学び始めるための基礎知識](https://qiita.com/os1ma/items/7a229585ebdd8b7d86c2), [MVCとか3層アーキテクチャとか勉強しなおし](https://fa11enprince.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/02/14/091434), 多分前記で言及されたS.O.記事の翻訳版[MVC対n層アーキテクチャ](https://www.dev4app.com/archives/698220-mvc-vs-n-tier-architecture.html), [私がMVCフレームワークをもはや使わない理由](https://www.infoq.com/jp/articles/no-more-mvc-frameworks/), [\[検索キーワード：MVC対n層アーキテクチャ\]検索結果](http://www.366service.com/jp/qa/search?q=MVC%E5%AF%BEn%E5%B1%A4%E3%82%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AD%E3%83%86%E3%82%AF%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1のWebサーバも、2のコントローラも、
>   「クライアントから指定されたURLに従って、下位層（アプリケーションサーバ、モデル）へ処理をリクエストする」

Webサーバにはその前に「クライアントとネットワーク経由で通信し、送られてきたデータをHTTPプロトコルとして解釈する/送信するデータをHTTPプロトコルに従って組み立てる」という仕事があります。一方、アプリケーションサーバには(一般論として)クライアントと通信する機能はありません。

```
http://example.jp/app/users/1
```

例えばこういうURLを考えたときに、Webサーバにとって意味があるのは、`/app`の部分です。一方、アプリケーション(コントローラ)にとって意味があるのは`/users/1`の部分です。

URLを受け渡ししているのでどちらもURLを解釈しているという大きな見方は間違っていませんが、実際に見ている視点は異なります。

「二重に処理をしているんのはなぜか」が疑問なのであれば、「二重に処理しないとどうなるか」を考えてみましょう。

- WebサーバにURLを解釈させないとすると、静的なファイル配信などの機能も全部アプリケーションに持ってくる必要があります。極端には、アプリケーションごとにWebサーバを実装するという話になります。もともとWebサーバにその機能があるのにわざわざそれを作るのはナンセンスです
- アプリケーションではなくWebサーバにコントローラの役割を持たせるというのは、CGIや素のPHPのモデル、要するに古のプログラムモデルです

Answer (score 4):

Web サーバーは、ファイルを配信するのに特化したような http サーバーです。よく使われるのは nginx かなと思っています。とにかくパフォーマンスが重要になるので、 C 言語で実装されています。

アプリケーションサーバーは、そうではなく任意のロジックを記述できるような http サーバーです。例えば rails や laravel などで実装することが多いかと思います。その関心ごとは、なるべく簡単にアプリケーションロジックを実装することです。

アプリケーションサーバー(のフレームワーク)だけで、サーバーを稼働させることは可能ではありますが、あまりパフォーマンスとして、良い結果にはならないです。例えば rails では、本番環境において静的ファイルのホスティングを行うことは、可能だけれども非推奨、とされています。

Web サーバーとアプリケーションサーバーを併用するとき、静的なファイルは Web サーバーで、アプリケーションでごりごり動的なページを計算するのはアプリケーションサーバーで分担します。（アプリケーションサーバーでごりごり計算する際には、 Web サーバーはアプリケーションサーバーに対するリバースプロキシとしてふるまうように設定する)

---

コントローラー(MVC)は、ですのでそもそも、アプリケーションサーバーをどう設計するか、においてのパターンの一つです。「http リクエストを受け取って、そのクエリパラメータやパスをパースし、適切なモデル上の計算を行なった上で、適切な view を選択しながらそれをレスポンスとする」ことに責務をおくのが一般的なのかな、と思っています。

Answer (score 0):

> ①このとき、Webサーバとコントローラはどんな違いがあるのでしょうか？

「Webサーバとアプリケーションサーバの責務の違い」だと思います。
　回答するのが難しい質問です。サーバとサーバ内の要素は比較のしようがありません。

> ②Webサーバが、指定されたURLに従ってアプリケーションサーバにリクエストを送った後、コントローラが、さらにURLに従ってモデルへ処理を依頼するという、2重でURLに従った処理を行っている理由は何でしょうか？

「Webサーバとアプリケーションサーバの責務が違うから」、または「Webサーバとアプリケーションサーバで行うべきこと、できることが違うから」です。
　「URLに従った処理」の内容はWebサーバとアプリケーションサーバで異なると思います。

「2重で」の表現に否定的なニュアンスを感じますが、将来の拡張や、別構成のシステムへの転用など設計の意図によっては「2重」が必要な場合もあると思います。